# Bash find and replace

Tags: bash

I have a workflow where I copy the Mac path on the server and replace it with a Windows path.
I'm using this bash function in my workflow:

```
    function nas () {
  echo -E $1 \
  | sed -e 's/^smb://g' \
  | sed -e 's/\//\\/g'
}

query=$1

nas $query
```

So I can convert this path:

```
smb://corp.atm.com/files/interdivisional/Graphics/11_DISPLAY/Neutral
```

to this:

```
\\corp.atm.com\files\interdivisional\Graphics\11_DISPLAY\Neutral
```

but I'd like to replace this part

**\\corp.atm.com\files\interdivisional\Graphics**\11_DISPLAY\Neutral

to this:
**I:**\11_DISPLAY\Neutral

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need `sed` for this -- bash has built-in search-and-replace support. See [BashFAQ #100](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100), *How do I do string manipulations with bash?*

Answer (score -1):

```
query='\\corp.atm.com\files\interdivisional\Graphics\11_DISPLAY\Neutral'
sed 's-\\\\corp.atm.com\\files\\interdivisional\\Graphics-I:-' <<<"$query"
```